# Setting an "attribute" for Theorem to be accessed later

Tags: tables, math-mode, macros, theorems, automation

I am writing a math paper with a large number of theorems. I'm looking to have a table summarizing my results, and I'd love it if the table could be generated automatically from my paper. I' looking to be able to do something like this

```
\begin{thm}
 \shortTheorem{$x + y = y + x$}
 Let $x,y$ be integers. Then $x+y=y+x$.
 \end{thm}
```

Note that shortTheorem is just the name I made up for whatever tag I put my desired text into.

Then, later on, I want to have a table which, for each theorem I define, prints its "shortTheorem" contents.
i.e.

- x + y = y + x

Are there existing packages to do this? If not, how would I go about writing my own macro to do so?

(Note: I couldn't figure out if there was a way to actually render a LaTeX table in my question, feel free to edit if you know how.)

Comment: This looks like something the endnotes package could do (or you could save the code directly) To show a latex image just use the image upload button to upload a cropped screenshot. It _always_ helps if you post a complete document in your question not just a fragment. Also in this case what other information do you want in your final list, you just show a bullet but you also want the theorem number?

Comment: My entire document is 30 pages spread out over 6 source files, so I don't think I'll be posting it in its entirety. As for information, the Theorem number would be nice, but all I really want is the text from \shortTheorem{} or some other tag to be put in the table.

Comment: I didn't mean post your orignal document I meant that example codes should have \documentclass and needed \usepackage to save people thinking about helping adding them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This makes a table at the end, which is I think what you wanted:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\shortthms{}
\def\shorttheorem#1{\g@addto@macro\shortthms{#1\\}}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}



\begin{thm}
 \shorttheorem{$x + y = y + x$}
  Let $x,y$ be integers. Then $x+y=y+x$.
 \end{thm}

\begin{thm}
 \shorttheorem{$x + x = x + x$}
 Let $x,y$ be integers. Then $x+x=x+x$.
 \end{thm}


blab blah

\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}}
\shortthms
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Plan b, using a file takes two latex runs to pull in the data:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%\def\shortthms{}
%\def\shorttheorem#1{\g@addto@macro\shortthms{#1\\}}

\def\shorttheorem#1{\immediate\write\shortthmout{\unexpanded{#1\\}}}


\def\shortthms{%
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}}\@input{\jobname.thm}\end{tabular}%
\newwrite\shortthmout
\immediate\openout\shortthmout=\jobname.thm}

\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}


\shortthms



\begin{thm}
 \shorttheorem{$x + y = y + x$}
  Let $x,y$ be integers. Then $x+y=y+x$.
 \end{thm}

\begin{thm}
 \shorttheorem{$x + x = x + x$}
 Let $x,y$ be integers. Then $x+x=x+x$.
 \end{thm}


blab blah


\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. The only thing is, is there a way to render the table earlier in the document than the theorems themselves? Ideally I'd have "summary of my results" followed by "detailed statement/proof for each theorem".

Comment: @jmite If you need that you need a different implementation that writes the text to a file. I dodn't do that as you said "...Then, later on, ..." which rather implied "not earlier":-)

Comment: I should have been more clear. Thanks anyways, it's quite a nice implementation.

Comment: @jmite version with table first added

Answer (score 6):

If you want also to print the theorem number, here's a schematic solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example

\newcommand{\shorttheorem}[1]{%
  \xdef\shorttheoremlist{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\shorttheoremlist}%
    \noexpand\item[Theorem \thethm:]
    \unexpanded{#1}}}

\newcommand\shorttheoremlist{}
\newcommand\printshorttheorems{%
  \begin{description}
  \shorttheoremlist
  \end{description}}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{thm}\shorttheorem{$x+y=y+x$}
Let $x$ and $y$ be integers. Then $x+y=y+x$.
\end{thm}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{thm}\shorttheorem{$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$}
Let $x$ be an integer. Then $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.
\end{thm}

\section{The final list}

\printshorttheorems

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Extended version

If you want to name the theorems in different ways and have them in the final list, then `cleveref` can come to the rescue. It's important to load also `amsthm` or `ntheorem` (I prefer the former) and to define the theorem-like environments *after* loading `cleveref`. Also, be sure to add the `\shorttheorem` bit at the start of the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcommand{\shorttheorem}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{shortcount}%
  \label{shortcount\theshortcount}%
  \xdef\shorttheoremlist{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\shorttheoremlist}%
    \noexpand\item[\noexpand\Cref{shortcount\theshortcount}:]
    \unexpanded{#1}}}
\newcounter{shortcount}
\newcommand\shorttheoremlist{}
\newcommand\printshorttheorems{%
  \begin{description}
  \shorttheoremlist
  \end{description}}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{lem}\shorttheorem{$x+y=y+x$}
Let $x$ and $y$ be integers. Then $x+y=y+x$.
\end{lem}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{thm}\shorttheorem{$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$}
Let $x$ be an integer. Then $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.
\end{thm}

\section{The final list}

\printshorttheorems

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Extended version with arbitrary placement in the document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newwrite\shorttheoremfile
\newcounter{shortcount}
\newcommand{\shorttheorem}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{shortcount}%
  \label{shortcount\theshortcount}%
  \xdef\shorttheoremlist{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\shorttheoremlist}%
    \string\item[\string\Cref{shortcount\theshortcount}:]
    \unexpanded{#1}^^J}%
}
\newcommand{\shorttheoremlist}{}
\AtEndDocument{
  \immediate\openout\shorttheoremfile=\jobname.thm
  \immediate\write\shorttheoremfile{\unexpanded\expandafter{\shorttheoremlist}}
  \immediate\closeout\shorttheoremfile
}

\newcommand\printshorttheorems{%
  \begin{description}
  \def\@noitemerr{\@latex@warning{Empty short theorem list}}%
  \@input{\jobname.thm}
  \end{description}
}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\section{Short theorems}

\printshorttheorems

\section{A section}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{lem}\shorttheorem{$x+y=y+x$}
Let $x$ and $y$ be integers. Then $x+y=y+x$.
\end{lem}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{thm}\shorttheorem{$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$}
Let $x$ be an integer. Then $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is quite nice. Is there any way to get the label of the theorem? I have mine labelled thm:foo and lem:bar so that I can decide whether to print Theorem, Lemma etc.

Comment: @jmite I was afraid you were to ask this. `;-)` Next step, be patient.

Comment: @jmite Here is a version that prints the different labels and allows arbitrary placement in the document (requires two runs to stabilize, as usual in these cases).